# How to run the Eclair client in terminal?

Tags: lightning-network, client, eclair

I'm trying to install Eclair on my machine according to [the instructions for installing
Eclair](https://github.com/ACINQ/eclair#installing-eclair). I downloaded the latest release, unziped the archive but coundn't find "eclair-node--<commit_id>/bin/eclair-node.sh". There is no "bin" subdirectory:

```
$ tree eclair-0.8.0/ -L 1
eclair-0.8.0/
├── BUILD.md
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── Dockerfile
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── SECURITY.md
├── codecov.yml
├── contrib
├── docs
├── eclair-core
├── eclair-front
├── eclair-node
├── monitoring
└── pom.xml

6 directories, 8 files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder structure you describe matches the source code of the repository. I think you accidentally downloaded the archive of the source code rather than the release binary of the node software.

On the [Eclair release page](https://github.com/ACINQ/eclair/releases/tag/v0.8.0), I see the same folder structure when I download the “Source code (zip)” (red arrow below), but you probably meant to download the “eclair-node-0.8.0-0077471-bin.zip” (yellow arrow) which when I unpack it has the folder you were looking for.

[image]